# Export Exchange calendar using EWS API

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am new to EWS managed API. I was wondering if there is any way to export an exchange calendar using EWS API to an ics file. I searched and found ways to create and retrieve calendar items but couldn't find a way to export a calendar. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn672317(v=exchg.150).aspx. There's a section of that article that talks about exporting to iCal format (which is the format .ics files use).